# Django Populate DateTimeField validation Error

Tags: django, django-orm

This is mym models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

I am trying to populate this field like this:

```
Post.objects.create(timestamp='20-03-20 8:56')
```

and throws me following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“20-03-20 8:56” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified, the format is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]
```

Hence you can construct this with:

```
Post.objects.create(timestamp='2020-03-20 8:56')
```

It might however be more convenient to pass a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC

Post.objects.create(timestamp=datetime(2020, 3, 20, 8, 56, tzinfo=UTC))
```

You can of course select another timezone instead.